# AWS (Elastic Beanstalk) + Java (Spring) = Reason: Error reading from remote server

Tags: java, spring, jpa, amazon-web-services, tomcat7

I do not speak English. (I am Brazilian).

I'm trying to run a Java webapp with Spring4 + JPA2 + Hibernate4. At my local server currently runs cool, put on AWS after some time working happens the following error:

Link: http://almocaquiweb-a.elasticbeanstalk.com/rest/restaurant/C1F15300-8BFC-496B-B90C-CF57596C8319/detail

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
> The proxy server could not handle the request GET /rest/restaurant/C1F15300-8BFC-496B-    B90C-CF57596C8319/detail.
>
> Reason: **Error reading from remote server**

My Files: (Do not use any XML file, all settings with annotations and Java classes.)

application.properties

```
# Server
server.port=8080
server.sessionTimeout=30

# MVC
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp

java.runtime.version=1.7

#DataSource
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xx.database.windows.net:1433;database=xxx;encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.poolPreparedStatements=true

# JPA
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.sqlserver.SqlServer2008SpatialDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.autocommit=true
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true

# Tomcat
tomcat.accessLogEnabled=false
tomcat.protocolHeader=x-forwarded-proto
tomcat.remoteIpHeader=x-forwarded-for
tomcat.backgroundProcessorDelay=30
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
server.session-timeout=40
```

RestaurantRestController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/restaurant")
public class RestaurantRestController {

    private final RestaurantService service;

    @Inject
    public RestaurantRestController(final RestaurantService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{uuid}/detail", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public Restaurant getDetail(@PathVariable("uuid") String uuid) {
        Restaurant restaurant = service.getRestaurant(uuid);          
        return restaurant;
    }
}
```

RestaurantServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Validated
public class RestaurantServiceImpl implements RestaurantService {

    private final RestaurantRepository repository;
    
    @Inject
    public RestaurantServiceImpl(final RestaurantRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
     @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Restaurant getRestaurant(String uuid){
        return repository.findOneByUUID(uuid);
        
    }
}
```

## Edit (including log)

I realized after a while (possibly the session expires), locally takes almost a minute to "reopen". Follows the log:

```
2014-07-07 10:32:29 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/rest/restaurant/c1f15300-8bfc-496b-b90c-cf57596c8319/detail'; against '/rest/restaurant'
2014-07-07 10:32:29 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/rest/restaurant/c1f15300-8bfc-496b-b90c-cf57596c8319/detail'; against '/rest/restaurant/**'
2014-07-07 10:32:29 DEBUG o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy:180 - /rest/restaurant/C1F15300-8BFC-496B-B90C-CF57596C8319/detail has an empty filter list
2014-07-07 10:32:29 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet:838 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/almocaqui/rest/restaurant/C1F15300-8BFC-496B-B90C-CF57596C8319/detail]
2014-07-07 10:32:29 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:246 - Looking up handler method for path /rest/restaurant/C1F15300-8BFC-496B-B90C-CF57596C8319/detail
2014-07-07 10:32:29 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:251 - Returning handler method [public com.snowmanlabs.almocaqui.domain.Restaurant com.snowmanlabs.almocaqui.rest.controller.RestaurantRestController.getDetail(java.lang.String)]
2014-07-07 10:32:29 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'restaurantRestController'
2014-07-07 10:32:29 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet:925 - Last-Modified value for [/almocaqui/rest/restaurant/C1F15300-8BFC-496B-B90C-CF57596C8319/detail] is: -1
2014-07-07 10:32:29 DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor:87 - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2014-07-07 10:32:29 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:249 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
2014-07-07 10:32:29 DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager:334 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1f85dbd] for JPA transaction
****2014-07-07 10:32:29 DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager:367 - Creating new transaction with name [com.snowmanlabs.almocaqui.service.implement.RestaurantServiceImpl.getRestaurant]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
2014-07-07 10:33:24 DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager:403 - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@565da00b]
2014-07-07 10:33:24 DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager:755 - Initiating transaction commit
2014-07-07 10:33:24 DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager:510 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1f85dbd]
2014-07-07 10:33:25 DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager:603 - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2014-07-07 10:33:25 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor:145 - Written [com.snowmanlabs.almocaqui.domain.Restaurant@48e83911] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@5bfa9eb7]
2014-07-07 10:33:25 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet:1012 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2014-07-07 10:33:25 DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor:112 - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2014-07-07 10:33:25 DEBUG o.s.o.j.EntityManagerFactoryUtils:435 - Closing JPA EntityManager
2014-07-07 10:33:25 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet:991 - Successfully completed request
```

**This delay on the server that hours works and hours returns the error  "Error reading from remote server"**

---

## Edit 2

I think the problem is the time of connection to the database, I tried to configure a connection pool.

dbConfig.java file

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:db.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.snowmanlabs.almocaqui.repository")
@Configuration
public class dbConfig {
 
    @Autowired
    Environment env;
 
    @Bean
    public BoneCPDataSource boneCPDataSource() {
 
        BoneCPDataSource boneCPDataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();
        boneCPDataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClass"));
        boneCPDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        boneCPDataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        boneCPDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        boneCPDataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes(60);
        boneCPDataSource.setIdleMaxAgeInMinutes(420);
        boneCPDataSource.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(30);
        boneCPDataSource.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(10);
        boneCPDataSource.setPartitionCount(3);
        boneCPDataSource.setAcquireIncrement(5);
        boneCPDataSource.setStatementsCacheSize(100);
 
        return boneCPDataSource;
 
    }
 
    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
 
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(BoneCPDataSource dataSource) {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(env.getProperty("jdbc.database-platform"));
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);
 
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.snowmanlabs.almocaqui.domain");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
 
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
 
        factory.setJpaProperties(properties);
 
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
 
        return factory.getObject();
    }
 
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        JpaDialect jpaDialect = new HibernateJpaDialect();
        
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        txManager.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect);
        return txManager;
    }
 
}
```

**Error after 10 minutes (closed session)**

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
> this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Jul 08 15:01:52 BRT 2014 There was an unexpected error
> (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Could not open JPA
> EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
> org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:

Comment: HI, I am getting a same problem, When testing locally, I am able to access the controller, however when i uploaded war to AWS, I’m getting resource not found.
This error was generated when i integrated spring boot with jpa, earlier to that there was no problem.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app server probably sits behind a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). Typically reverse proxy has a timeout setting. If the time it takes to obtain an answer from the backend is longer, it will give that error.

Similar problem happened to me once and it was because I used `localhost` host reference. Turns out `localhost` could be ambiguous, it can be interpreted as ipv4 or ipv6. In some configuration switching between ipv4 and v6 took so long and proxy error occured.

Since then I switched into using `127.0.0.1` so it wouldn't switch to ipv6.

Comment: Yes it can be. On my local server, is taking nearly 1 minute to start the application, it takes a long time to connect to SQL Server on another server (Windows Azure). How could I change this? The only thing I have is access to the terminal SSH Shell and do not know anything beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

My response is:

```
{"name":"Peperone Buffet","categories":[],"address":"Rua A, 4","wifi":false,"parking":false,"cards":[],"free":23.23,"kilo":45.34}
```

So either you already fixed it:) or your error related to your local network settings, and not related to Spring or AWS, your application is OK.

Comment: The system began operating did not fall over since yesterday, I have not changed anything after this topic. Yesterday was accessing 10 minutes and 10 minutes: Something happened internally, nothing in the logs was registered and began to sitada error message appears. (This happened all day yesterday) *Sorry my english